# How to execute two different directives with $parsers and $validators on a same element?

Tags: angularjs, validation, parsing, angularjs-directive

Issue is that only the first directive is working and other one is not. Provided below are the two directives. Both works fine when working alone.

```
  .directive("restrictInvalidInput", function($rootScope, utils) {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          require: "ngModel",
          priority: 1,
          link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
              var remove_invalid_chars = function() {
                  //blah blah
              };

              ctrl.$parsers.push(remove_invalid_chars);
          }
      }
  })

  .directive("validateUsername", function($rootScope, utils) {
      return {
          restrict: "A",
          require: "ngModel",
          priority: 2,
          link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

              var validate_username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                  //blah blah
              };

              ctrl.$validators.valid_username = validate_username;
          }
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is where you put `blah blah`. Are you sure, that parser returns a value? Because ([from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)):

> Returning `undefined` from a parser means a parse error occurred. In that case, no `$validators` will run

[WORKING PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/hZcEz5gZ1V6bFNxaIuMz?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Some name';
  }])
  .directive("restrictInvalidInput", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        priority: 1,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var remove_invalid_chars = function(viewValue) {
                console.log('Look, I\'m parsing');
                return viewValue;
            };

            ctrl.$parsers.push(remove_invalid_chars);
        }
    }
})
.directive("validateUsername", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        priority: 2,
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            var validate_username = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                console.log('Look, I\'m validating');
                return true;
            };

            ctrl.$validators.valid_username = validate_username;
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <input type="text" 
           ng-model="name" 
           restrict-invalid-input 
           validate-username 
    />
    {{name}}
</div>
</div>
```